# Always get a blank black window without showing triangles shown in the OPENGL programming guide 8th edition

Tags: c++, opengl

I've been trying to build the program of the first example in the Opengl Programming guide book(8th edition), but all I got is a blank black window without showing two triangles. I've checked all the compilations, and it seems to be all fine. Could anyone give me some help please?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <glew.h>
#include <FreeGL\freeglut.h>

using namespace std;

GLint attribute_v=-1; // global variables
GLuint vertexbuffer;
GLuint VertexArrayID;
GLuint program;
int width=500; int height=700;

struct ShaderInfo
{
    GLenum vshader;
    const char* vertexfile;
    GLenum fshader;
    const char* fragmentfile;
};

const char* getshaderprogram(const char* filename, string& shader)
{
    fstream shaderFile( filename, ios::in );
    if ( shaderFile.is_open() )
    {
        std::stringstream buffer;
        buffer << shaderFile.rdbuf();
        shader = buffer.str();
        buffer.clear();
    }
    shaderFile.close();
    return shader.c_str();
}

GLuint LoadShaders(ShaderInfo shaderinfo)
{
    GLuint program;
    //load and compile vertex shader
    GLuint vertexshader=glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint fragmentshader=glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    string shaderprogramtext;
    const char*     Vertexshadersource=getshaderprogram(shaderinfo.vertexfile,shaderprogramtext);
    const GLint vlength=shaderprogramtext.size();
    glShaderSource(vertexshader,1,&Vertexshadersource,&vlength);

    glCompileShader(vertexshader);
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<shaderprogramtext.size();++i)
    {
        cout<<Vertexshadersource[i];
    }
    cout<<endl;
    GLint status;
    glGetShaderiv( vertexshader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status );

    if( status!=GL_TRUE )
    {
        std::cerr<<"unable to compile the vertex shader..."<<endl;
    }
    char* infoLog=new char[100];
    GLsizei buffsize=0;
    glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexshader,buffsize,NULL,infoLog);
    for(int i=0;i<buffsize;++i)
    {
        cout<<infoLog[i];
    }
    cout<<endl;
    delete[] infoLog;

    //load and compile fragment shader
    string fragmentshadertext;
    const char* Fragmentshadersource=getshaderprogram(shaderinfo.fragmentfile,fragmentshadertext    );
    const GLint flength=fragmentshadertext.size();
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<fragmentshadertext.size();++i)
    {
        std::cout<<Fragmentshadersource[i];
    }
    cout<<endl;
    glShaderSource(fragmentshader,1,&Fragmentshadersource,&flength);
    glCompileShader(fragmentshader);

    glGetShaderiv( fragmentshader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status );
    if ( status != GL_TRUE )
    {
        cerr << "\nFragment Shader compilation failed..." << '\n';
    }
    infoLog = new char[];
    buffsize = 0;
    glGetShaderInfoLog( fragmentshader, buffsize, NULL, infoLog );
    for ( int i = 0; i < buffsize; ++i )
    {
        cout << infoLog[ i ] << endl;
    }
    delete [] infoLog;

    // create the shader program
    program = glCreateProgram();
    // attach the vertex and fragment shaders to the program
    glAttachShader( program, vertexshader );
    glAttachShader( program, fragmentshader );

    // link the objects for an executable program
    glLinkProgram( program );
    GLint compiled;
    glGetProgramiv( program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &compiled );
    if ( !compiled )
    {
        cout << "Link failed..." << endl;
    }

    cout<<"Program:"<<program<<endl;

    // return the program
    return program;
}

void init(void)
{
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);

    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);
    GLdouble vertices[6][2] = {
    { -0.90, -0.90 }, // Triangle 1
    { 0.85, -0.90 },
    { -0.90, 0.85 },
    { 0.90, -0.85 }, // Triangle 2
    { 0.90, 0.90 },
    { -0.85, 0.90 }
    };
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    ShaderInfo shaders = { GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "vertex_shader.txt" , GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "fragment_shader.txt" };
    program = LoadShaders(shaders);

    glUseProgram(program);
    glVertexAttribPointer(attribute_v, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(attribute_v);
    const GLchar* attribute_name = "attribute_v";  // this name has to be the same variable name in the vertex_shader file. 
    attribute_v = glGetAttribLocation(program, attribute_name);   // check attribute activated. 
    if (attribute_v == -1)
    {
        cout<<"could not bind attribute for vertex..."<<endl; 
    }
}

void display(void)
{
    //glClearColor(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(200,200);
    glutInitContextVersion(4,2);
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
    glutCreateWindow("Triangle Visualization");

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE; 
    if (glewInit())
    {
        cerr << "Unable to initialize GLEW ... exiting" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    cout << "The version of opengl is : "<<glGetString(GL_VERSION)<<endl;

    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrong order of statements here:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(attribute_v, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(attribute_v);
const GLchar* attribute_name = "attribute_v"; 
attribute_v = glGetAttribLocation(program, attribute_name);
```

You're using `attribute_v` before assigning a value to it. Since it was initialized to -1, the `glVertexAttribPointer()` and `glEnableVertexAttribArray()` will result in `GL_INVALID_VALUE` errors.

```
const GLchar* attribute_name = "attribute_v"; 
attribute_v = glGetAttribLocation(program, attribute_name);
glVertexAttribPointer(attribute_v, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(attribute_v);
```

If you have any kind of issue with OpenGL rendering, it's always a good idea to call `glGetError()` to check if any error conditions were triggered.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it's helpful really. And I fixed the order of statements as you suggested, but I still get the same result. I use the glGetError() in my display functions , and it shows that I got Error 1280 which is a GL_INVALID_ENUM error. I don't think I passed the invalid enum to the function, where's going wrong exactly?

Comment: I added the glGetError() after the glewinit(), I got error 1280, what is going on here? looking forward to your reply, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This may very well be a video card driver issue. Not sure what your environment is but this is what worked for me.

Environment: Dell Inspiron 15 7559, Nvidia GeForce GTX 960M, Ubuntu 15.10

Install order matters, specifically install the video card package last. Note that you want to update your OS to the latest version first. Also, if your OS is 32bit then append ":386i" to the end of all the package names. If a 32bit version doesn't exist then apt-get will let you know. However most people are running 64bit Linux if they're working with OpenGL 4.x.

One note on the video card drivers, the apt repositories may not give you the latest driver, which was the case for me with the "nvidia-current" package. I had to find the name of the most recent Nvidia package by opening the Ubuntu Software & Updates utility:

[image: Ubuntu Software & Updates Utility (screen grab)]

Here are the packages that you need for the OpenGL Redbook 8th Edition, and the order in which to install them:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
sudo apt-get install libxmu-dev libxmu-headers
sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev
sudo apt-get install libglew1.10
sudo apt-get install libglew-dev

# Bad!
#sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
# Good :)
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352-updates
```